# Possible to use named placeholders in DBI's selectcol_arrayref & Co.?

Tags: perl, sqlite, postgresql, dbi

Is it somehow possible to use named placeholders where DBI allows @bind_values?  E. g., I would like to make statements like:

```
my $s = $DB->selectcol_arrayref ("SELECT a FROM b
                                  WHERE c = ? OR d = ? OR e = ?;",
                                  {},
                                  $par1, $par2, $par1) or
        die ($DB->errstr ());
```

less prone to mistakes.  I'm using DBD::Pg and DBD::SQLite.

Comment: Placeholder support (and what sorts of placeholders are supported) depends on the driver so I added some more tags.

Comment: Is there any reason to think you can't? DBI says `$ary_ref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($statement, \%attr, @bind_values)`. Note that you can pass `undef` for the second arg instead of creating an empty hash.

Comment: @ikegami: Maybe you could explain how to use *named* placeholders in the `@bind_values` arguments to any of the DBI methods. If you're using `prepare`/`bind_param`/`execute` it is easy but I've never figured out how to do it without a bunch of explicit `bind_param` calls.

Comment: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/ch05_03.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What sorts of placeholders (if any) are supported [depends on the driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values):

> **Placeholders and Bind Values**
>
> Some drivers support placeholders and bind values.
>   [...]
>   Some drivers also allow placeholders like *:name* and *:N* (e.g., *:1*, *:2*, and so on) in addition to *?*, but their use is not portable.

But you're in luck, the [PostgreSQL driver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#Placeholders) supports named or numbered parameters:

> There are three types of placeholders that can be used in DBD::Pg. The first is the "question mark" type, in which each placeholder is represented by a single question mark character.
>   [...]
>   The method second type of placeholder is "dollar sign numbers".
>   [...]
>   The final placeholder type is "named parameters" in the format ":foo".

And the [SQLite driver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-SQLite/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm#Placeholders) also supports them:

> SQLite supports several placeholder expressions, including ? and :AAAA.

The downside is that you'll end up using `bind_param` a lot with the named parameters so you won't be able to use conveniences like `selectcol_arrayref` and `$sth->execute(1,2,3)` (**Note:** If anyone knows how to use named placeholders with `execute` I'd appreciate some pointers in a comment, I've never figured out how to do it). However, you can use the various forms of number placeholders (such as `select c from t where x = $1` for PostgreSQL or `select c from t where x = ?1` for SQLite).

Also be aware that PostgreSQL uses colons for array slices and question marks for some operators so sometimes the standard *?* placeholders and *:name* named placeholders can cause problems. I've never had any problems with *?* but I've never used the [geometric operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html) either; I suspect that sensible use of whitespace would avoid any problems with *?*. If you're not using PostgreSQL arrays, then you probably don't have to worry about [array slices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) fighting with your `:name` named placeholders.

---

**Executive Summary**: You can't use named placeholders with `selectcol_arrayref` or similar methods that work with `@bind_params`. However, with SQLite and Postgresql, you can use numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ... for Postgresql or `?1`, `?2`, ... for SQLite) with the methods that work with `@bind_params` or you can use named placeholders (`:name` for both PostgreSQL and SQLite) if you're happy using the longer `prepare`/`bind_param`/`execute`/`fetch` sequence of methods and you'll have to be careful if you use PostgreSQL arrays in your queries.

Comment: Thanks.  Using "$1" & Co. in `selectcol_arrayref` isn't that fool-proof, so I'll probably use the `prepare`/`bind_param`/`execute`/`fetch` where I think it is necessary.

Comment: @Tim: You could always write your own utility function that took an SQL string and a hash-ref, then it could `prepare`/`bind_param`/`execute`/`fetch` and return the summarized results. That sort of thing would be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: Yep, but that's just another cog I would have to "develop" and maintain. In general, I stick as much as possible to the products of other people's brains who usually have thought much more about any corner cases that could be encountered than I could even imagine :-).